# Print rounded digits without extra zeros

Tags: java

I'm trying to round using `BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP` but am not getting expected results. This code:

```
String desVal="21.999";  
BigDecimal decTest=new BigDecimal(
    String.valueOf(desVal)
)
.setScale(
    Integer.parseInt(decimalPlaces), BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN
);     
System.out.println(decTest);
```

Gives the following results:

```
decimalPlaces=1 it is displaying 21.9 //correct 
decimalPlaces=2 displaying 21.99 //correct 
decimalplaces=3 displaying 21.999 //correct 
decimalplaces=4 displaying 21.9990 //incorrect
```

I want to get the following:

```
decimalPlaces=1 should display 21.9      
decimalPlaces=2 should display 21.99 
decimalplaces=3 should display 21.999 
decimalplaces=4 should display 21.999
```

Is there a way to do this with standard Java (ie no external libraries)?

Answer (score 3):

Use [BigDecimal#stripTrailingZeros()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#stripTrailingZeros%28%29):

```
String[] decimalPlaces = new String[] {"2", "2", "3", "4", "4"};
String[] desVal = new String[] {"20", "21.9", "21.90", "21.99999", "21.99990"};

for (int i = 0; i < desVal.length; i++) {
    BigDecimal decTest = new BigDecimal(desVal[i]);

    if (decTest.scale() > 0 && !desVal[i].endsWith("0") &&  !(Integer.parseInt(decimalPlaces[i]) > decTest.scale())) {
        decTest = decTest.setScale(Integer.parseInt(decimalPlaces[i]),
                BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN).stripTrailingZeros();
    }
    System.out.println(decTest);
}
```

Output:

```
20
21.9
21.90
21.9999
21.99990
```

Comment: @Thanks Mena,It will fail if the value already has zero in the end .Suppose take value is 21.9990,after running your code it will give the output as "21.999"

Comment: @RajuKomaturi wasn't that _exactly_ the point of your post? Sorry, I don't understand here...

Comment: @RajuKomaturi sorry now I got your point. Edited my answer to add a **weak** workaround by checking whether the original `String` ends with a "0" or not. This of course would have unexpected results for integer number representations such as "20".

Comment: @This approach also wont work,if decimalPlaces=5 and value is 21.9990.then it will give the result as 21.99900

Comment: @RajuKomaturi so in that case it should return the same 21.9990, right?

Comment: @RajuKomaturi ok I've edited my answer again, so now it should match all the unspecified conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
int decPlaces = Math.min(Integer.parseInt(decimalPlaces), 
                         desVal.length() - desVal.indexOf(".") + 1);
BigDecimal decTest=
      new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(desVal)).
             setScale(decPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.text.NumberFormat

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

System.out.println(nf.format(decTest));
```

If you want to preserve original scale, then

```
String desVal="21.99901";  
BigDecimal decTest=new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(desVal)); 
int origScale = decTest.scale();
decTest = decTest.setScale(4, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
System.out.println(String.format("%."+origScale+"f", decTest));
```

Comment: ,trailing zero loosing,if original value has '0' ex:21.9990

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print trailing zeroes, but not all of them, you will need a [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html).
The trick is that in your case, you need to build the Format String depending on the number of decimals in the original input String.

```
    int decimalPlaces = 10;
    String desVal="21.99900";  

    // find the decimal part of the input (if there is any)
    String decimalPart = desVal.contains(".")?desVal.split(Pattern.quote("."))[1]:"";

    // build our format string, with the expected number of digits after the point
    StringBuilder format = new StringBuilder("#");
            if (decimalPlaces>0) format.append(".");
    for(int i=0; i<decimalPlaces; i++){
        // if we've passed the original decimal part, we don't want trailing zeroes
        format.append(i>=decimalPart.length()?"#":"0");
    }

    // do the rounding
    BigDecimal decTest=new BigDecimal(
        String.valueOf(desVal)
    )
    .setScale(
        decimalPlaces, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN
    );   

    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat(format.toString());
    System.out.println(nf.format(decTest));
```

Comment: @Hendrickx: One issue i found it,if decimal places is 0.it is displaying as "21."

Comment: @RajuKomaturi Indeed.  I edited it to also add the point conditionally.